# How are the extra terms calculated in this equation?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

[image]

I am trying to understand this equation but not getting very far because I don't get why there are 7 terms at the end when it is a square and hence should only be 4. I thought that maybe extra derivatives are being calculated on the go but it still remains unclear..

If anyone can tell me what I'm missing thatd be appreciated

Comment: Some of the fractions inside the first brackets are not ordinary numbers, they are differential operators. And a differential operator applied to a product generates two terms.

Comment: Ah yep I had a look at how to deal with the operators and figured out how to expand it correctly thanks!